# Stochastic geometry, point processes online lecture

Tags: geometry, reference-request, stochastic-processes

Does any of you know where to find online lecture/podcast introducing stochastic geometry and/or point processes?

Thank you!
Riccardo

Comment: Cavallri Could you be more specific? If you are interested in stochastic geometry of a point of view of statistical mechanics models in lattices type $\mathbb{Z}^n,\;n\in\mathbb{N},$ I can try to help you.

Comment: I'm approaching stochastic geometry to study wireless networks.

Comment: Let me add that all my knowledge about probability comes from the book "Probability, Random Variables, and Stochastic Processes" (A. Papoulis). So a good reformulation of my question could be: which material do you suggest me as a starting point for approaching stochastic geometry?

Answer (score 1):

It really is very difficult to find introductory notes on this subject. My suggestion is as follows.:

- [Classical stochastic geometry](http://fds.oup.com/www.oup.com/pdf/13/9780199232574_chapter1.pdf) (*broken link*)(http://fds.oup.com/www.oup.com/pdf/13/9780199232574_chapter1.pdf)
- "A crash course in stochastic geometry" by Adrian Baddeley: [chapter 1](http://school.maths.uwa.edu.au/~adrian/reprints/chapter1.ps) and [chapter 2](http://school.maths.uwa.edu.au/~adrian/reprints/chapter2.ps) (short notes)
- [An Introduction to Stochastic Geometry](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/10617/10617A.pdf) (paper).
- [Géométrie stochastique et théorie de l'information](http://smai.emath.fr/smai2011/slides/baccelli/Slides.pdf) by François Baccelli, 2011 (slides, in English except the title)

I hope this helps.

OBS. For an nonintroductory approach  of stochastic geometry (focused on statistical mechanics and Ising's model) see [this paper](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~georgii/papers/ghm.pdf) by H.-O. Georgii.

Answer (score 1):

How about the book by Haenggi:
http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/engineering/wireless-communications/stochastic-geometry-wireless-networks?format=HB

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no as such video lectures on stochastic differential geometry. The David william's (vol. 2) book is good introductory text on stochastic geometry.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, stochastic geometry is the study of random spatial patterns. At the heart of the subject lies the study of random point patterns. This leads to the theory of spatial point processes, hence notions of Palm conditioning, which extend to the more abstract setting of random measures.

I recommend these books related to stochastic geometry:

- Stochastic Geometry for Wireless Networks (Martin Haenggi)
- Stochastic geometry and its applications ( Sung Nok Chiu, Dietrich Stoyan,et al.)
- Stochastic Geometry for Wireless Networks – Haenggi
- Stochastic Geometry and its Applications – Stoyan, Kendall and Mecke
- New Perspectives in Stochastic Geometry – Kendall and Molchanov, eds.
- Stochastic Geometry and Wireless Networks Volume I: Theory – Baccelli and Błaszczyszyn
- Stochastic Geometry and Wireless Networks Volume II: Applications – Baccelli and Błaszczyszyn
- Random networks for Communication: From Statistical Physics to Information Systems – Franceschetti and Meester
- Analytical Modeling of Heterogeneous Cellular Networks: Geometry, Coverage, and Capacity – Mukherjee
- Poisson processes – Kingman